# iOS App with subscription always gets rejected

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

We have problems releasing our Newstand App to the App Store.
It always gets rejected, because the validation of the receipts coming from the subscription In-App-Purchase seem to fail in the live (non-sandbox) environment.
The thing is, we tested everything against the sandbox environment and everything works fine. For the release version, we made sure that we use
our validation webservice that validates against the apple live-service, NOT the sandbox validation service.
So everything should work, but in the review process it always fails.

Does anyone have experience with similar problems?
Apple does test against the live-environment, right? Because we have to submit the live-Version of our App, validating against sandbox does not make sense.

We submitted the IAP items together with the App, but that should not be a problem, as the Apple testers seem to be able to purchase the subscription,
just the validation does not work.

Comment: did you make a video of using the app against the sandboxed environment showing how it is intended to work, and add it under review notes on iTunes Connect?

Comment: You should contact Apple regarding this issue. They can provide more information than we can.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I found sth in the Apple documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2259/_index.html
(way down under Frequently Asked Questions 16.)

"How do I verify my receipt (iOS)?
Always verify your receipt first with the production URL; proceed to verify with the sandbox URL if you receive a 21007 status code. Following this approach ensures that you do not have to switch between URLs while your application is being tested or reviewed in the sandbox or is live in the App Store."

We misread the line above "Use the production URL http://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt once your application is live in the App Store.", thinking Apple would use real server validation iin review process, but they also use sandbox environment.

Difficult to find this little line, they should make that fact more prominent in my opinion!

So hopefully this will resolve the issue.

Thanks for your comments though!